# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to pass the array through urlSearchParams

```
interface ContainerProps {
  name: string;
  query: string;
  cuisine: any[];
  location: any[];
}

fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search"+ 
new URLSearchParams({query: query, cuisine: cuisine, location: location}))
```

I am getting this error:

> Argument of type '{ query: string; cuisine: any[]; location: any[]; }'
> is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] |
> Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined'.   Types of
> property 'cuisine' are incompatible.
> Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an object with three properties (query, cuisine, and location) to the URLSearchParams constructor, which expects a record of key-value pairs where both the key and value are strings. In your case, the cuisine and location properties are arrays of unknown types.

You should probably convert the cuisine and location arrays to strings before passing them to URLSearchParams. You could use the Array.join() method to create a comma-separated string of the array elements. like this;

```
const params = new URLSearchParams({
  query,
  cuisine: cuisine.join(','),
  location: location.join(','),
});

fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search?${params}`);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I tried to use toString() but it never worked and the error still persisted. Nice to know another way of doing this.